# Linear Operators satisfying $S^n=0$ but $S^{n-1}\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I need help with part (c). I could do part (a) and part (b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $S^{n-1} \neq 0$, then there exists $x$ such that $S^{n-1}x \neq 0$. Consider the vectors $\{x, Sx, S^2x, \ldots, S^{n-1} x \}$, and try to draw the connection with the "shift" property from the matrix $A$ (and the operator $T$) from the previous parts.

Comment: After doing this I see that the matrix formed by the above vectors satisfies one condition of the matrix $A$. 
But I think I still need to prove that these vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Yes, yes you do =)

Answer (score 0):

The conceptual way of proving this is as follows. Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator of an $F$-vector space. We have an **evaluation homomorphism of $F$-algebras** $\phi:F[x]\to \text{End}(V)$ defined by the rule $\phi(p(x))=p(T)$ (here $F[x]$ denotes the polynomial ring in one variable over $F$ and $\text{End}(V)$ denotes the $F$-algebras of endomorphisms of the $F$-vector space $V$).

If $T^{n}=0$, then that's saying that there is an induced homomorphism $\bar{\phi}:F[x]/(x^n)\to \text{End}(V)$. Furthermore, if $T^{n-1}\neq 0$, then that's saying that the induced homomorphism $\bar{\phi}$ is injective. Can you take it from here? (It's a little bit subtle but this conceptual approach is used a lot, e.g., in at least one proof of the Jordan canonical form which is a relatively deep theorem in linear algebra.)